# Error 415 Web service Rest with Spring

Tags: spring, web-services, rest

i'm having a problem with my service. I'm trying to send the datas to the database. However, i'm receiving this message:

Error 415

The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

I'm using Postman to sendo the code below:

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYPzo.png)

Controller:

```
package br.com.standard.controller;

import java.util.List;
import br.com.standard.bean.Client;
import br.com.standard.service.ClientService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class ClientController {


        @Autowired
        ClientService clientService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/addClient", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
        public void addClient(@RequestBody Client client) {
            clientService.addClient(client);

        }

}
```

Model

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="client")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    String nome;

    public Client() {
        super();
    }

    public Client(int id, String nome) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }



}
```

I know that it probably is a simple question, but i tried a lot of ways without success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two (alternative) solution proposals:

1. Be sure to send the header: `Accept=application/json`! (with your client.)
2. ...or change `headers = "Accept=application/json"` to
   `consumes = org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` (leaving everything else as is)